# cannot read parameters sent by RedirectAttribute in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller for `/` and another one for submitting form, I want to redirect to `/` controller after form submission with message saying registered successfully.

here is my controller for `/`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mainPage(@RequestParam(value = "registerSuccessful", required = false) boolean registerSuccessful,
                       ModelMap modelMap) throws UnknownHostException {
    boolean isDeviceRegistered = mainService.isDeviceRegistered();
    modelMap.addAttribute("isDeviceRegistered", isDeviceRegistered);
    modelMap.addAttribute("registerSuccessful", registerSuccessful);
    return "main";
}
```

and the controller for `/registerForm`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "registerForm", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public String saveDeviceInfo(@ModelAttribute("deviceInfo") DeviceInfo deviceInfo,
                             RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                             BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap){
    mainService.saveDeviceInfo(deviceInfo);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("registerSuccessful", true);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

as you see, I send `true` for attribute `registerSuccessful` but when I read contents of `registerSuccessful` on `/` handler after redirect, it is false.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ModelAttribute` like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mainPage(@ModelAttribute(value = "registerSuccessful") boolean registerSuccessful,
                       ModelMap modelMap) throws UnknownHostException {
    boolean isDeviceRegistered = mainService.isDeviceRegistered();
    modelMap.addAttribute("isDeviceRegistered", isDeviceRegistered);
    modelMap.addAttribute("registerSuccessful", registerSuccessful);
    return "main";
}
```